# What are the differences in casual controls and regular controls?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

In Pokémon Sword/Shield, there is an option in the game settings turn on “casual controls”. The I -game description of this states

> This mode makes it easier to play with one hand

Earlier this year, I was gifted with my first child so I often find myself playing games with one hand. When I enabled this setting, a majority of the controls seemed somewhat the same.

So what are the differences in casual controls and regular controls?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Casual Controls allow you to play with *single* JoyCon, be it right or left.

1. Right stick can move both character and menu
2. Arrow buttons are turned into action buttons. UP is X, DOWN is B, LEFT is Y, RIGHT is A
3. Right stick click will work as whistling

In both modes R/L and ZL/ZR works as accept button in most menus. 
Only downside of enabling Casual Controls I have noticed is loss of "D pad" for browsing menu.

Casual Mode affect Pro Controller as well as JoyCon halves, it is safe to assume all controller types are affected.

Comment: Ah ha - I play with the Pro Controller, so didn't really occur to me that this setting was more towards using the Joycons. Thanks for the answer! Despite playing with the Pro Controller, the buttons/analogs seem to line up with this answer as well. The changes to the D-Pad is annoying though

Comment: @PTwr - Any reason you made this answer a community wiki?

Comment: @Robotnik I thought the list of differences will grow once we get to later content, and expected it to end up as collaborative work.

Comment: @PTwr Fair enough. If you want I can revert it to a standard answer so you get the reputation, up to you :)

Comment: @Wondercricket It's not really "more towards using the Joycons". The change to the D-pad isn't annoying if you want to use only your left hand, as I often do. If you don't, then don't turn this option on...

Comment: Just to add on, you won't be able to use the Right Stick for changing directions/navigating around Wild Area too.